# Regex : parsing a file location

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse the file location using regex but I am getting extra characters when i use regex. The line that I am trying to parse is

```
 A HREF="/MISO/getEQRFile;jsessionid=1JgnSTXhgvbpSYLVhp3h4ZpGltNpphxr1ncwlGnK3YXsh2phxKh9!794217179?entity=WEPM&nodeId=key0">EQR_WEPM_20131001_123354_M_082013.zip</a></b></td>
```

I need the text between the quotes. Currently I am using

```
^.+?<A\s*?HREF\s*?=\W(.+?.+?>) but it gives me the value 

match.Groups[1].Value: /MISO/getEQRFile;jsessionid=1JgnSTXhgvbpSYLVhp3h4ZpGltNpphxr1ncwlGnK3YXsh2phxKh9!794217179?entity=WEPM&nodeId=key0">
```

which is an extra "> in the end. I would appreciate if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex sure is strange... Note that you should use a proper HTML parser if you're trying to parse HTML.

What's wrong with your regex is that you have `>` inside the capture, so that it'll get anything up to `>`.

Try using a negated class:

```
^.+?<A\s*?HREF\s*?="([^"]+)"
```

Or if you have single and/or double quotes:

```
^.+?<A\s*?HREF\s*?=(["'])(.*?)\1>
```

And use `match.Groups[2].Value`.

Comment: The problem is that my boss wants me to use regular expression. He is kindda pain in the A**

Comment: Thanks Jerry, it does work for me. I am getting the right value that I need. I used the first option and it worked.

Comment: I was trying to read more about regular expression, But I its really tough to find a good reference.

Comment: @user2754845 I think that a good start is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Otherwise, as usual, practise makes perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex replace command and use:

```
(<A\s*?HREF\s*?=\W(.+?.+?>))([^<]*)(</a\s*>)
```

replacing by the 3rd group (the filename itself)

```
\3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Jerry already helped me out with a solution. I sure will try this yours too when I get time.